# Java - VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token, when assigning value to an instance variable

Tags: java, class, variables, object

I'm studying linked lists from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htzJdKoEmO0) video from UC Berkeley. However, when I try typing the same version in my Eclipse compiler, like this....

```
public class CreateLinkedList{

    public class Node{
        String PlayerName;
        Node next;
    }


    Node first = new Node();
    Node second = new Node();
    Node third = new Node();

    first.PlayerName = "Sanchez";
    second.PlayerName = "Ozil";
    third.PlayerName = "Welbeck";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

I get the error "Syntax error on token "PlayerName", VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token" on the following lines

```
first.PlayerName = "Sanchez";
second.PlayerName = "Ozil";
third.PlayerName = "Welbeck";
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review [nested class definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)... If you want to set the properties from a static context... you need a static class.

```
public class CreateLinkedList{

static class Node{
    String playerName;
    Node next;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node first = new Node();
    Node second = new Node();
    Node third = new Node();

    first.playerName = "Sanchez";
    second.playerName = "Ozil";
    third.playerName = "Welbeck";

    System.out.println("First is : " + first.playerName);
    System.out.println("Second is : " + second.playerName);
    System.out.println("Third is : " + third.playerName);

    }
}
```

If you wish to keep your inner class as a nested public class then you need to instantiate the upper class first.

```
public class CreateLinkedList {

    public class Node {
        String playerName;
        Node next;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Node first = new CreateLinkedList().new Node();
        Node second = new CreateLinkedList().new Node();
        Node third = new CreateLinkedList().new Node();

        first.playerName = "Sanchez";
        second.playerName = "Ozil";
        third.playerName = "Welbeck";

        System.out.println( "First is : " + first.playerName );
        System.out.println( "Second is : " + second.playerName );
        System.out.println( "Third is : " + third.playerName );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
Node first = new Node();
Node second = new Node();
Node third = new Node();

first.PlayerName = "Sanchez";
second.PlayerName = "Ozil";
third.PlayerName = "Welbeck";
```

is not in a code block, try moving it to `main`.

Also the `Node` class will need to `static`, or else move it to a seperate .java file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize like this

```
first.PlayerName = "Sanchez";
second.PlayerName = "Ozil";
third.PlayerName = "Welbeck";
```

You have to move it to some of the methods of `class CreateLinkedList`
If you are putting it in main you have to declare the Node instances `static`

```
static Node first;
static Node second;
static Node third;
```

Comment: Okay, that works. But any reason why they have to be initialised inside a method? Also, why isn't the professor in the video doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

shouldn;t these lines be in main() function :

```
Node first = new Node();
Node second = new Node();
Node third = new Node();

first.PlayerName = "Sanchez";
second.PlayerName = "Ozil";
third.PlayerName = "Welbeck";
```

Comment: Are you asking or stating?